# Laravel multilpes where Like with array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I need query of my model  with method (where) and using LIKE to find results;

Its my code:

```
public function scopeTags($query, $tags)
{
    /*
     * random = [ 'tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3', ...]
     */
    $random = $tags[rand(0, count($tags) - 1)];
    return $query->where('tags', 'LIKE', "%{$random}%");
}
```

I need something like that:

```
public function scopeTags($query, $tags)
{
    /*
     * random = [ 'tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3', ...]
     */
    foreach($tags as $tag) {
        $random[] = "%{$tag}%";
    }
    return $query->where('tags', 'LIKE', $random);
}
```

What's the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a extra `where` function call for each tag:

```
public function scopeTags($query, $tags)
{
    /*
     * random = [ 'tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3', ...]
     */
    foreach($tags as $tag) {
        $query->where('tags', 'LIKE', "%{$tag}%"); //this will be a AND
        //$query->OrWhere('tags', 'LIKE', "%{$tag}%"); //this will be a OR
    }
    return $query;
}
```

or if you need to simulate `WHERE (tags like '%tag1%' AND tags like'%tag2%' AND ...) AND (something else)` with parenthesis:

```
public function scopeTags($query, $tags)
{
    return $query->where(function($q) use($tags) {
        foreach($tags as $tag) {
            $q->where('tags', 'LIKE', "%{$tag}%"); //this will be a AND
            //$q->OrWhere('tags', 'LIKE', "%{$tag}%"); //this will be a OR
        }
        return $q;
    });
}
```